# Navigation Routes

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to go to my home page on tap of a Middle screen button. For some reason I have already emptied the Navigation Stack.

I tried runApp(MyApp());
Its not working

```
    onTap: () {
      print('sdg');
      runApp(MyApp1());
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Navigator`

> Navigator.push(context,
>           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WidgetName()));

in your case use

```
onTap: () {
      print('sdg');
       Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp1()));
      }
```